# Want to make android app which would search or give suggestion when we types first letter

Tags: java, android, search, caption

I have created an app for my college project were a person can search restaurant by name, the problem is the user has to type the exact name what I have given in the database, I want to make it like this way

If a person types just a letter "n" the app should show all the restaurant starting with n

or

if a user types letter "a" then the app should suggest and show all the restaurant name starting with letter "a"

The current code is pretty simple

```js
if(NAME.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString(1)))
     {     
     str1=str1+"\nRestaurant Name:\n"+res.getString(1)+"\n\nRestaurant Addresss:\n"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n";
     }
```

Comment: Please consider providing what you've tried so far and an example of your code where you're trying to achieve this.

Comment: As of now I have the code where the user has to give the exact same name  or a restaurant

if (NAME.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(res.getString(1)))
{     
str1=str1+"\nRestaurant          Name:\n"+res.getString(1)+"\n\nRestaurant Addresss:\n"+res.getString(2)+"\n\n";
}

Comment: I'll try to give it in the question itself here it is messing it up

Answer (score 1):

The component which you are looking for is `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Example usage and documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html)